# Which classes of drivers require an ABI bump for Windows 8.1?

Tags: drivers, kernel, windows-8.1

I noticed that Windows 8.1 installed a lot of new drivers for several of my devices, but I don't know if that's because there was just an updated one available on Windows Update, or if the kernel interface for that device class actually changed.

Let's say you have a device for which Windows 8.1 itself doesn't ship a driver with the OS. Perhaps older, perhaps newer.

Let's also assume that this device works fine on Windows 8 with an older driver.

For which classes of device in this scenario, would the working Windows 8 driver fail to work on Windows 8.1?

I already know that GPU drivers seem to strongly expect (if not outright require) an update for Windows 8.1, because Microsoft introduced WDDM 1.3 with Windows 8.1, which isn't supported on Windows 8, so trying to use a Windows 8 graphics driver on Windows 8.1 would only provide WDDM 1.2 support at the latest, and maybe confuse DWM. But what other kernel interfaces/ABIs were bumped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that the [Network Driver Interface Specification (NDIS) is bumped to 6.40 in Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn449742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the [Server Message Block (SMB) to 3.02.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2013/10/02/windows-server-2012-r2-which-version-of-the-smb-protocol-smb-1-0-smb-2-0-smb-2-1-smb-3-0-or-smb-3-02-you-are-using.aspx)